# Returning max integer but getting control may reach end of non-void function error

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program that returns the maximum integer within an input file where every integer is read in one at a time. However, I keep getting the control may reach end of non-void function and I don't know why. (error is pointed out at line 13)

```
int display2_int(int max){
  int n = read_int();
  if(n != READ_INT_FAIL){
    if(n > max){
       display2_int(n);
    }else{
      display2_int(max);
    }
  }
  else{
    return max;
  }
}

 int main(void) {
  int first = read_int();
  display2_int(first);
}
```

Comment: Your function has three paths through it. Only one of them returns a value. (Count the `return` statements.)

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on the code.

Comment: Is it correct, that display2_int will call display2_int and again and again?

Answer (score 1):

If the branch `if(n != READ_INT_FAIL)`... is entered, then the function will recursively call itself, but it will not "return" a value. You are lacking `return`-statements in this branch:

Write

```
if(n > max){
   return display2_int(n);
}else{
   return display2_int(max);
}
```

Comment: But once it hits the else statement, won't the function return max and then just exit?

Comment: BTW thanks, that fixed the problem.  But can you still clarify my confusion in my above comment?